# How to disable this sound?

Tags: windows-10, audio, touchpad, virtual-desktop, system-sounds

I hear [this](https://vocaroo.com/i/s0TgG7lb6p1O) sound when I am scrolling through multiple virtual desktops in windows 10. This specifically happens if I use my laptop's touchpad (Elan-touchpad). However, the same is not true for external usb mouse. I have looked into the touchpad settings and did not find any setting to disable it.

Windows OS Build Version : 1803

**Update 1:** From the volume mixer panel I can confirm that it is a system sound. So, I tried disabling the windows sound scheme in the sound control panel by selecting the `No Sounds` scheme. However, I can still hear the sound when I am horizontally scrolling through the multiple virtual desktops in task view using the touchpad.

**Update 2:** I uninstalled the Elan PS/2 Touchpad drivers. Now I don't hear the sound anymore however, the functionality of touchpad is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-precision-touchpad-drivers) regarding installing Windows Precision Drivers. I rollbacked to the previous driver " Elan PS/2 Touchpad " which I had previously uninstalled. Followed the article by updating rollbacked driver and the problem is solved now. I no longer hear any sound while horizontally scrolling in the task view(seems like a bug with the previous driver) and as a bonus I got more functionalities in my touchpad due to Windows precision drivers.